# Mixing audio with HDMI video to replace the sound from the camera

Tags: audio, hdmi, mixing, embedding

I would like to live-stream from a camera, but replace the audio from the camera with a higher-quality mixed soundtrack, ready for sending over HDMI to a transmission device.

How can I do this?

I know that the Tascam DR-701D has two HDMI ports (in and out). Could I use this as the mixer to replace the soundtrack on the HDMI video feed, ready for transmission, or is there a better way?

**Details**

The video will come from the micro-HDMI port on the camera.

The audio will come from one of three sources:

1. XLR stream from the event
2. Directional XLR mic
3. MP3 player

The audio will be mixed together by a mixer during the event as appropriate.

I now need to mix the audio from the sound mixer with the video from the camera’s HMDI port (which will have an unusable poor-quality audio track from the camera). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you are looking for is an **HDMI audio embedder**.

It seems that the Tascam DR-701D offers this functionality as described in [Outputting this unit's audio as the HDMI output audio](https://tascam.jp/downloads/tascam/896/e_dr-701d_rm_vb.pdf)

Examples of external alternative such products can be found here (I am not affiliated with these manufacturers, other products might exist):

[Kramer FC-69](https://www.kramerav.com/us/product/FC-69)

[Extron HAI 100 4K](https://www.extron.com/product/hai1004k)

Comment: Thank you. I have also discovered that video monitors often have this functionality built-in. For example the BlackMagic Video Assist 4K and the Video Devices Pix-E5.